# Add query params to current route Angular2/4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a parent component on the route '/parent', it has a links e.g.

```
<a routerLink="./" [queryParams]="{query: value}">
```

I have a component in the nested route '/parent/child', that listens for query params change. The problem is that parent component generates links without child route e.g. "/parent?query=value". Is there any way to only add query params to current route from parent component?

```
{
  path: 'route/:value/:value_two',
  component: component,
  canActivate: [GuardService],
  children: [{
      path: '',
      component: commonComponent
    }, {
      path: 'child1',
      component: childOneComponent
    }, {
      path: 'child2',
      component: childTwoComponent
  }]
}
```

Comment: can you show your defined route file

Comment: @PranayRana yes, look it after edit, I've simplified it

Comment: so you want like parent/childonecoponent ??

Comment: @PranayRana in my parent component i have a link like I've shown in example, and when child route is loaded I want get url with query params by clicking that link, but it generates link without child route like parent?query, I want to get parent/child?query, or parent?query if no child loaded

Comment: @PranayRana it just removes current route and gives me parent route

Comment: can check my answer ...you are looking for that

Comment: unfortunately it is not what I'm searching, my routes in the <a> tag should be generated, not hardcoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working for me

route

```
{ path: 'component-two', component: ChildOne,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'child-one', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'child-one', component: ChildOne },
      { path: 'child-two', component: ChildTwo }
    ]
  }
```

route link

```
<a [routerLink]="['/component-two/child-two']" [queryParams]="{ page: 99 }">Component Two</a>
```

in ts file

```
 private ngOnInit() {
     this.sub = this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        // Defaults to 0 if no query param provided.
        this.id = +params['page'] || 0;
      });
  }
```

in parent component you can do like this

```
<nav>
  <a [routerLink]="['./child-one']">Child One</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['./child-two']">Child Two</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: I think it should be like <a [routerLink]="['./', activeChildRoute]"..., but how to get the active child route from parent component? I mean the route which is in router-outlet of parent component

Comment: @AlexanderBondarenko - if you do like [routerLink]="['/component-two"] it will give you child-one ...

Comment: But what if I'm in child two and click that link, I need to stay in child two and the route should change only query params

Comment: I've made method which returns Router.url, and pass it to routerLink. It works, but I think there should be more elegant solution.

Comment: @AlexanderBondarenko - then this works like @Component({
  selector: 'child-two',
  template: `Child Two test
  <a [routerLink]="['/component-two/child-two']" [queryParams]="{ page: 100 }">Component Two</a>
  `
})..rest code remain same

Comment: I mustn't hardcode link, I could be in child-two or child one, it doesn't matter, there could be event child 3 but the link should be the same. The link should get current url and add query param

Comment: @AlexanderBondarenko - if you want to go to parent from child just do like this  <a [routerLink]="['/component-two']" [queryParams]="{ page: 100 }">Component Two</a>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a route like **/parent/child** then you can use:

```
<a [routerLink]="['parent', 'value']" >
```